# Calling Custom functions from Python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Is there a way to call functions defined in a file say myfunc.r

```
---------------myfunc.r --------------
myfunc = function(){
  return(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
}

getname = function(){
  return("chart title")
}

---- Python 
   How to call getname() here ?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: Why do you define `myfunc` here?

Comment: @agstudy: just an example showing that the file can contain several functions, I think.

Answer (score 21):

There are features in rpy2 that should help making this cleaner than dumping objects into the global workspace.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
# if rpy2 < 2.6.1 do:
# from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
# STAP = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
with open('myfunc.r', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
myfunc = STAP(string, "myfunc")
```

The objects in the R file can now be accessed with `myfunc.myfunc` and `myfunc.getname`.

Check the documention about [importing arbitrary R code as a package](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package).

Comment: `SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage` The name is a little bit long I think..for R and python develoopers:)

Comment: Yes, may be on the Java extravaganza end of the naming spectrum but still under 140 characters ;-). A shorter class name while keeping it clear would mean introducing a subpackage. Suggestions for names are also welcome.

Comment: Of course I came from the .net world and I know what you mean. rpy2 is a great work. I appreciate. +1.. long name but clean solution! I think  you can just add `import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage as STAP` for example...

Comment: @agstudy: I edited the code snippet; now the real class name is written only once

Comment: string = ''.join(f.readlines()) will give errors. What you should do for R version 3.2.0  (at the time or writing) is like this string = f.read().replace('\n', '')

Comment: I tried this except that my function is called `calc_num` so I ran `myfunc=STAP(string, "calc_num")` and I get a `rpy2.rinterface.RParsingError`

Comment: @KillerSnail : an `RParsingError` indicates that when parsing the R source code contained you the Python string `string` R stopped with a parsing error. In other words, whatever is in `string` did not seem valid code to R itself.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like this ( python code here)

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r('''
       source('myfunc.r')
''')

 r_getname = robjects.globalenv['getname']
```

then you call it

```
r_getname()
```

Comment: This still worked for me in 2016 with `R-3.2.2` and `rpy2=2.7.0` :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use what **user3282437** suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567081/rpy2-import-external-r-file):

```py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r_source = robjects.r['source']
r_source('/path_to_file/myfunc.R')
r_getname = robjects.globalenv['getname']
```

I'm not sure that it's a global issue, but on my Windows machine direct call like **agstudy** advised:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r('source("some_file.R")')
```

leads to python crash.