# Rpy2 import external R file

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have a R script in a .R file that I would like to execute. How can I load it?

I'd like to `source("/path/to/file.R")` within the python code, but with this name!

Answer (score 4):

Simply import R's `source` function like any other!

```py
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r_source = robjects.r['source']
r_source("path/to/file.R")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick to have both R code and Python script in my editor, you can have a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55900840/5350311 , I hope it is useful for you.