# Calling R Script from python in AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, rpy2

I know there is a package called rpy2 in python in order to integrate R and python.

> [Calling R script from python using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544190/calling-r-script-from-python-using-rpy2), in this link they have described to do normally.

But in order do the same in AWS lambda, what should be the path that we can give instead of the name "folder" in this link.

Answer (score 1):

I am using very simple methode for interachanging between python and R by using rpy2, here is one example where I write R script as string and then use rpy2 to translate it for R and return it back,

```
   path="H:/projects/somepackage/CODE"
   from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
   string = """
   setwd <- function(x) {
   setwd("%s")
   return (getwd())}
   """ % (path)
   print (string)
   powerpack = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "powerpack")
   #The R functions setwd can be  called with powerpack.setwd () as
   powerpack.setwd()[0]
```

I am not sure if it might be useful in your case but if you somehow manage to transfer your code to AWS you will definitely get the results... You can also try to save the string as a file, then ask Python to compile it as external function(I used to do so in the past without rpy2)

Cheers