# Load r-script or block of code from AWS and Python 2.7 into R, via rpy2

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2

Best

I've a R-script, which is located on my amazon S3 Bucket.
What I want to do is, I would like to create a python 2.7 programm which can run R-scripts, (which are located and streamed via a S3-bucket).
To do this, i would like to use the rpy2 library (without downloading the script itself temp. (thus : `s3.get_object()` unstead of `s3.download_file()` )).

Main question:

how do I load, the R-script into R, without downloading it.
because :

```
def __init__(self, r_script):
    self._r = robjects.r
    self._r.source(r_script.read())
```

or

```
def __init__(self, r_script):
    self._r = robjects.r
    self._r.source(r_script)
```

Doesn't work ... because it is not a location-string but already the code itself

Here is the content of my test script :

```
rm(list = ls())

test1<- function(){}

test2<- function(){}

test3<- function(){}

execute<- function(){

  a <- c(1,2,3)
  c <- c(1,2,3)
  b <- c(1,2,3)

  r <- data.frame(a,b,c)

  return(r)
}
```

- Actually, I think it would be already fine, if I could parse a big block of code, like the above, as a R script. (because, r_script.read(), is ~ a big string (I think))

Kind regards

Comment: Curious, why not have Python call the R script via command line with *Rscript.exe*?

Comment: because, there will be more +/- 15 interactions between the R and python environment. Python will call data from DynamoDB, or S3 and parse it to R, which will receive it knwoledge back, which can be stored again  etc, 
:)

Comment: Got it! A very important tidbit to include.

Answer (score 2):

`rpy2` can let you [parse](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/rinterface.html#parsing-and-evaluating-r-code) a string as R code before evaluating it, and  this is used in an helper class making a Python namespace out of the string containing R code (See
[Calling Custom functions from Python using rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419740/calling-custom-functions-from-python-using-rpy2)).

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import STAP
mymodule = STAP(r_script, "mymodule")

# call a function
mymodule.execute()
```

Note: I am seeing `rm(list=ls)()` at the beginning of your R script. If your R script is meant to be a library it should not assume anything about the frame in which it is executed. To help with that, the class `STAP` above will execute the R code in a new enviroment (not R's `GlobalEnv`).